# Position of html canvas on web page

Tags: javascript, css, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I have a canvas based script similar to ***dottydots***. Its working fine but i want to change its canvas position. I tried this position:absolute. It works but it only move canvas`s visual area. I mean the working area of canvas is (where we use mouse pointer to do something on canvas) remain at old position.

Comment: Do you have any codes ? Or JSfindle example ?

Comment: yes ,, you can see my working area at current time on my website`s logo. [link]http://mr-saini.cu.cc @Arthur

Comment: i am using thi code

    <html>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="logo/jquery.js"></script>
  
<script type="text/javascript">
      var text_to_draw = "Mr-Saini.Cu.Cc";
      var image_to_draw = false;
      var densityOverride = 3;
</script>
<canvas id="c" width="1000" height="600"></canvas>
<script type="text/javascript">
var main = document.getElementById("c");
var render = main.getContext("2d");
main.style.left = "200px";
main.style.top = "180px";
main.style.position = "absolute";
    </script>
<script src="logo/main.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    
</html>

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have issues retrieving the right mouse coordinates.
You have to use getBoundingClientRect to have them right.

So, provided you are not using with/height in css to scale the canvas, the
formula will be :

```
var mousePos   = [-1, -1];
var canvasRect, canvasLeft, canvasTop
function updateCanvasRect() {
    canvasRect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
    canvasLeft = canvasRect.left;
    canvasTop  = canvasRect.top ;
}
function updateMousePos(e) {
   mousePos[0] = e.clientX - canvasLeft;
   mousePos[1] = e.clientY - canvasTop ;
}
```

you must call

> updateCanvasRect

after document loaded, and then on scroll if you allow scroll.

Comment: script is working but problem is only in canvas position.. mouse pointer only give response to canvas from top.right portion of screen.. but the canvas is at the centre of screen .. i want both of them on same position ...

you can see that in the logo of my website http://mr-saini.cu.cc @gamealchemist